# Python Bokeh DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated

Tags: python, datetime, warnings, bokeh

I recently installed Bokeh on my Mac computer and I am using it for a Python application. Every time, I run this application, it gives the following **Deprecation Warning**:

```
.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/core/json_encoder.py:52: 
DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated;    
this will raise an error in the future
NP_EPOCH = np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')
```

I tried to search in google about it, unfortunately I could not find something related it. Moreover, at the end of the warning, it says, this warning will raise an error in the future. Does anybody has idea regarding what is going on here?

I also tried following statements to suppress it (as suggested [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9242)), however it also did not work out:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning, module='.*/bokeh/*.')
```

I just tried this, but also did not work out:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```